# Bind border style to current user control

Tags: wpf, binding, border

I`m developing a wizard application which has a side menu with 5 borders and a content control that contain application screens (user controls).

The borders styles are suppose to give to user an indication where he is at the wizard steps.

I wrote 2 border styles - the first one is the defult style which applied on all borders by default.
The second one (isFoucusedStyle) need to be applied by the border that suitable to the current screen.

For example when the wizard is showing the first screen: first border need to use the isFoucusedStyle and the others need to use defult style. When the user continues to next screen, the first border need get back to default style and the second border now will apply isFoucusedStyle.

I create the pages instances via xaml at the mainWindow under resources at the next way:

```
     xmlns:view="clr-namespace:App.View"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:App.ViewModel"

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:OpeningViewModel}">
        <view:OpeningView/>
   </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:PersonalDataViewModel}">
        <view:PersonalDataView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:BusinessDataViewModel}">
        <view:BusinessDataView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:BusinessDataViewModel}">
        <view:BusinessDataView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I also have a property - CurrentPage which binded to ContentControl - when the user clicks "next page button" CurrentPage updates and the ContentControl switch UserControl.

There is no any binding between the borders to User Controls, in my current state the borders are just visual graphics without any features.

How can i implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took the "isFoucusedStyle" and config it to baseOn defultstyle.
I added triger to isFoucusedStyle which turns on when Border.Focusable is true.
I Created a converter which has access to current page number.
At every border I bounded focusable property to the converter and sent it "converter parameter" with the suitible page number (page number which represented by current border) 
The converter is checking for equility between currentPageNumber to converterParameter and returns boolean result.
The result is turning on (or not) the trigger and set the needed border style.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would strongly suggest you base your wizard on the NavigationWindow (or containing a NavigationFrame), this will give you all your back and forwards navigation for free, and if you want you can always re-style your NavigationWindow to match a more wizard like interface (see [WPF Wizards](http://alski.net/post/2012/01/11/WPF-Wizards.aspx)). NavigationWindow/Frame also supply you with Navigate() methods that handle the transition between pages.

In order to handle the navigation links (your five side menu items) I bind each link to a View level ICommand which tests to see if we need are already on the correct page in CanExecute. Setting ths borders is then just a case of `{Binding CanExecute, Converter={BoolToColorConverter}}`.

In your case, you can simply do the same thing. Setup your command to check if we have the right CurrentPage, and Bind as above using a Converter.